# C# как с помощью точки на цифровой клавиатуре сымитировать нажатие Tab

Tags: c#, textbox, tab

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку . (Del) на цифровой клавиатуре переходить к следующему текстовому полю. Похожие решения я нашёл, но нигде не могу найти название этой клавиши, чтобы подставить в e.KeyData == Keys.???

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Есть хакеские заморочки по емуляции клавы, но тут достаточно сделать `SetFocus` нужному елементу.

Comment: `Keys.Decimal` при включенном `NumLock`, она же `Keys.Del` при выключенном. При выключенном `NumLock` цифровой блок просто дублирует соответствующие клавиши и отличить их нельзя, разве что на уровне драйвера, и то не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Если задача стоит - нажать на кнопку Tab (и сменить фокус на другой элемент управления)

(Примеры с TextBox'ом)

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            SendKeys.Send("\t");

    }
```

Если задача стоит - получить в том же TextBox'е сам символ Tab (т.е. \t)

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete)
            e.KeyChar = (char)Keys.Tab;
    }
```

P.S. Можно пользоваться хуками клавы, но это уже кардинальные меры для такой задачи.

Comment: P.P.S. Пишу с ноута, тут нет другого делета, по ангиологии думаю заберетесь. Коды клавиш хранит в себе "Keys"